# Secure empty trash on external drive OSX

Tags: secure-erase

I’ve got an internal SSD on a 2018 MBP, with these drives macOS no longer gives you the option to secure erase the trash.

I’ve connected an older HDD external drive which I wish to secure erase the trash on, how can i do this in OSX 10.13 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To securely “empty” the trash on an external drive you can use the `rm` command with the `-P` option which will overwrite it 3 times - similar to a DoD 3-pass overwrite.

```
% rm -P /Volumes/foo/bar/.Trash/*
```

The other option is to reinstall `srm` via [Homebrew](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/282436/119271) or [Macports](https://ports.macports.org/port/srm/summary) and use `srm` in place of `rm`

```
% srm  /Volumes/foo/bar/.Trash/*
```

You could even create an alias and put it in your `.zprofile` or `.bash_profile` depending on the shell you’re using.

```
alias emptytrash=‘rm -P /Volumes/foo/bar/.Trash/*’
```

Comment: Note: This answer does not work for modern macos. According to the macos 14.3.1 man page for rm:

-P      This flag has no effect.  It is kept only for backwards compatibility with 4.4BSD-Lite2.

Therefore using -P is no more secure than not using it.

Answer (score 0):

Secure erase relies on writes replacing the data in the blocks allocated for a file. With SSDs this is technically not possible. If you want to protect data on an external drive, you need to encrypt it (can be done with a right-click on the drive in Finder).

PS: encrypting external drives is advisable in general, otherwise anybody with physical access to the drive can access its content.